# How to write common gherkin for Given,And,Then in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I need to write a step definition which applicable in And,Then,Given.
What is the format?

Comment: And I don't use reg expressions but variables in step definitions..

Comment: Just opening cukes.info solves descripted problem. Please, specify it more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber does not actually care about whether you defined the step definition with "Given", "And", "When" or "Then". Basically any Given/And/When/Then will call any step definition with the matching regex, regardless of its says Given/And/When/Then.

For example:

A feature with all given/and/when/then using the same regex:

```
Feature: Shared Step

    Scenario: Given And When Then
        Given general step
        And general step
        When general step
        Then general step
```

A single step definition that matches the regex:

```
Given /general step/ do
    puts 'shared step'
end
```

Gives the following result, which shows that all are using the same step definition even though the step definition is 'Given':

```
 Scenario: Given And When Then # features\test.feature:3
    Given general step          # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:1
      shared step
    And general step            # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:1
      shared step
    When general step           # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:1
      shared step
    Then general step           # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:1
      shared step

1 scenario (1 passed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m0.011s
```